# Unobtrusive client validation data attributes are not rendered for nested property rules

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

Using FluentValidation 4.4, the following rules emit the correct unobtrusive validation data attributes on input fields:

```
RuleFor(e => e.PrimaryContact).NotEmpty();
```

rendering the following html:

```
<input class="text-box single-line k-textbox input-validation-error" 
       data-val="true" data-val-required="'Primary Contact' should not be empty." 
       id="PrimaryContact" name="PrimaryContact" type="text" value="">
```

However, a rule with a nested property does not emit any validation data attributes:

```
RuleFor(e => e.Company.Name).NotEmpty();
```

rendering the following html:

```
 <input class="text-box single-line k-textbox" id="Company_Name" name="Company.Name" type="text" value="">
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That could get a bit sloppy in the case that you need to validate on each property in the child object. I would recommend doing what they have on their [documentation here](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#ReusingValidators).

```
[Validator(typeof(ParentObjectValidator))]
public class ParentObject 
{
    public string PrimaryContact {get;set;}
    public Company Company {get;set;}
}

[Validator(typeof(CompanyValidator))] // This one is required!
                                      // Otherwise no data-val-required will be assigned
public class Company
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Set a validator for the child object.

```
public class CompanyValidator : AbstractValidator<Company> {
    public CompanyValidator() {
      RuleFor(company => company.Name).NotEmpty();
      //etc
    }
}
```

Then, in your parent object, you can set that validator to the child object like so.

```
public class ParentObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentObject> {
  public ParentObjectValidator() {
    RuleFor(e => e.PrimaryContact).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(e => e.Company).SetValidator(new CompanyValidator());
  }
}
```

This should point you in the right direction!

Comment: I was trying to avoid that since I had multiple company properties with different rules. In the end I created two separate company models with their own validator implementations.

Answer (score 2):

I already have the same Problem like "jrummel"!!!

If I define the Validator with SetValidator for my nested ViewModel Object, the MVC EditorFor Method didnt't render any data-val* attributes. And so no client side validation did work...

But every other property(which is not nested an the nested viewModelType) work very well. The inputs have the data-val* attributes. --> WTF?

After I found http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2013/04/17/fluentvalidation-and-mvc-from-server-to-client.aspx and I did understood how the validation mechanism did work, i recognized that I'm missing the `[Validator(typeof(MyNestedViewModelType))]` Attribute on MyNestedViewModelType class.

Hope this helps someone else to save time ;-)

Comment: Exactly same situation, Adding [Validator(typeof(...)] solved the issue but.... What if a childviewmodel is a sort of a generic viewmodel. And validation should occur depending on the parent context. This is where the real dilemma comes. Anyway thanks for sharing your thoughts it helped!!